# abspath() with __file__ as input

Tags: python

From reading stackoverflow I found out that `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file

Is there any reason for this line of code?

`os.path.abspath(__file__)`

Documentation states that

```
os.path.abspath(path)
Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path.
```

Does `abspath()` provide any value in this case?

Comment: `__file__` can be a relative path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure it would provide value to someone who wishes to know the path from where their code was run, without symlinks, `pathname/../otherpath` weirdness, or the other issues that `abspath()` addresses. See also the documentation for [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath). These two could conceivably be different.

It's interesting to note that this may vary from [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath), which returns "the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path (if they are supported by the operating system)."

**Interesting results**: on my OS X system, I have a folder in my `~/Dropbox` hierarchy (which resides on my standard filesystem) symlinked to another folder in `~/Library/Application Support` to provide plugin files for Sublime Text. When I run a test program from Sublime, I get the following results:

```
__file__           = /Users/MattDMo/Dropbox/Sublime/ST3_Mac/Packages/tk_test.py
abspath(__file__)  = /Users/MattDMo/Dropbox/Sublime/ST3_Mac/Packages/tk_test.py
realpath(__file__) = /Users/MattDMo/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/tk_test.py
```

However, running from Terminal (within `~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`) gives:

```
__file__           = tk_test.py
abspath(__file__)  = /Users/MattDMo/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/tk_test.py
realpath(__file__) = /Users/MattDMo/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/tk_test.py
```

Changing the directory in Terminal to `~/Dropbox/Sublime/ST3_Mac/Packages` doesn't make any difference in the results. Very interesting...

Comment: @Liondancer I just updated my answer with some interesting testing results showing various values of `__file__`, `abspath(__file__)`, and `realpath(__file__)` if you didn't see it yet...